# Removing archived directories after packing using tar and find

Tags: linux, find, tar, bzip2

I try to find directories, archive them and after that delete archives which were packaged.

I use following command:

```
find $DIRECTORY -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "`date --date="$i month ago" +%m`" -not -name \*.bz2 -print -exec tar --remove-files -cvjf {}.tar.bz2 {} \;
```

It works very good on tar (GNU tar) 1.23, input directory is being deleted. When I run it on tar (GNU tar) 1.15.1 there is strange behaviour. Directory which should be deleted still exist. Only its content(files) is removed.

I think that it could be caused by diffrent action in "remove-files" part.

I will be very gratefull for providing a solution to this problem.

Comment: Nobody knows how to do it?